# how to add bearer token to header get collection data using Angular firebase?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, token

how to add bearer token to header get collection data using Angular firebase ?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass custom headers to calls made with the Firestore SDK.

If you're using Firebase Authentication, the Firebase SDKs take care of passing the authenticated user with their calls. So details about the currently signed-in user should already be passed to Firestore.